# Find an element in a collection list using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach

I am looking for better solution for my problem. I have a collection of data in this format and wondering what is the quickest way to retrieve a data from the collection using typescript.

- First thing comes is identify by parsing each element in the collection and break out as soon once the element is identified.

We could use better solutions in C# and other languages. But, i am looking for better solution in typescript.

Here is the structure:

```
myData:
{
  Id: string,
  Name: string,
  Address: string
  Salary: number
  phone: number
}
```

Assume we have about 500 records where Id is unique. 
I show ONLY (ID & Name) in a table having checkboxes for each row of this data.

When i select some of the checkboxes, i would need to collect corresponding data of each row by going through this list and perform some action.

```
var selected: ImyData[];
for(var d in data)
{
  if(d.id == myId)
  {
    this.selected.id = d.id;
    this.selected.address = d.address
    this.selected.salary = d.salary
    return;
   }
 }
```

But this approach keeps checking each and every element in the collection and returns me the address which is not performance effective. Wondering any suggestions to achieve in typescript?

Comment: The sample data is not really sample data: you've given a structure.

Comment: Anything you can do in JavaScript, you can do in TypeScript. So search for "finding an object by id JavaScript" and you'll find plenty of answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Are you known with dictionaries/hashsets? I'm pretty sure you need that instead of looping over the items with a lookup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a function to iterate object, use destructuring assignment to get only `"Id"` and `"Name"` properties within `for..of` loop, if matched, `return` property references as object from function.

```js
const myData = {
  Id: "a",
  Name: "b",
  Address: "123",
  Salary: "456",
  phone: "789"
}

let myId = "a";

const getIdAndName = (data, id) => {
  for (let {Id, Name} of [myData]) 
    if (Id === id) return {Id, Name}; 
  return `${id} not found in data`;
}

let IdAndName = getIdAndName(myData, myId);

console.log(IdAndName);
```

Comment: this also loops all the data every time?  (50% in the average case for every lookup)

Comment: @Julian Not sure what you mean? The approach at your Answer loops data 100% of time, by creating a new object, yes?

Comment: it's init once, and then retrieve without loop. Init is `O(n)`, lookup is `O(1)`. If you need 10 items, then it's `O(n+10)`. Your lookup is `O(n)`, so with 10 lookups is `O(n * 10)`.

Comment: So with 500 items, this checks 500*10=5000 items, with mine 500+10 = 510

Comment: @Julian Then your Answer is essentially suggestion to adjust data structure to accommodate  expected requirement? In which case, loop would not be necessary  for either Answer; solution would be to change data structure, to for example, utilization of `Map`, where each item will be unique; then `mapInstance.get("a")`

Comment: yes you could also start with  `Map` (or dictionary, hashset, assoc array), or convert it once.

Comment: @Julian Agreed. Have you considered including that suggestion within your Answer? That is, adjust data structure to not have to perform loop at all; unless the data is an array of objects where `"Id"` of property is not unique within the set of objects.

Comment: sounded out of scope for me. And the initial load is only once, not every lookup. That a huge performance improvement when selecting multiple checkboxes.

Comment: @Julian Not sure how that suggestion is out of scope for Question? Your Answer performs the same task. The original object is only referenced by means of an additional object. If original object is composed to meet expected requirement, an additional object or loops would not be necessary. Unless Question is inquiring as to look up alone, without changing data structure. Interesting. Perhaps OP can review the exchange and gain further perspective as to what they are trying to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142118/discussion-between-julian-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 3):

You could create a "dictionary" (aka assoc array, hashtable or map) in Javascript, and get the item like this, which is `O(1)`

```
var selected = allItems[id];
```

With a `for` loop you could initial create your dictionary. You will do the `for` loop only once and every lookup is very fast (because it don't need a `for` loop)

Example:

```js
//init, do this once!
var initObjects = [{ id: "id1", name:"name1" }, { id: "id2", name:"name2" }]

var dict = {};

for (i = 0; i < initObjects.length; i++) {
    var item = initObjects[i];
    dict[item.id] = item;
}

//retrieving values. No loops! O(1) complexity. Very fast!
console.log(dict["id2"])
console.log(dict["id1"])
```

(`O(1)` = constant lookup time independent of the size of your list. So lookup in list with 100 or 1000000 items costs the same time)

Comment: Agree. Just load once and keep lookup the list n number of times !

Comment: @Born2Code Approach by @Julian completes in less time than approach at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43506568/, see `console` at  https://jsfiddle.net/g14hoLcw/